# Comma separated list in twig

Tags: php, twig

What is the shortest (and clearest) way to add comma after each element of the list except the last one?

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {{ role.name }},
{% endfor %}
```

This example will add comma after all lines, including the last one.

Comment: Do you mean comma including the last one or excluding the last one?

Comment: I want comma separated list, so excluding the last one.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Don't know about shortest but this could be clear.  Try the following to add comma after all lines in the loop except the last one:

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {{ role.name }}
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Shorter version as suggested in comments:

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {{ role.name }}
    {{ not loop.last ? ',' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is not working with `{%for loop if statment %}`

Comment: Maybe to clean that up a bit go with `{{ not loop.last ? ',' }}`

Comment: To avoid spaces before and after comma: `{{- not loop.last ? ', ' -}}`

Answer (score 25):

This works with Symfony 2.3.x but should work with every 2.x version:

```
{{ user.roles|join(', ') }}
```

Comment: if you work with a collection of objects, just implement the __toString() method

Answer (score 2):

> {{- not loop.last ? ',' : '' -}}

Answer (score 2):

{{ user.roles|column('title')|join(', ') }}

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP asked for iterating on `name` key of a `role`.

Shortest would be:

```
{{ user.roles|column('name')|join(', ') }}
```

where `user.roles` is a list of user roles.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I managed to print author names (in `authors` array) in some scientific publication format using twig's local `loop` variable in `for` loop-

```
    {% spaceless %}
     {% for author in authors %}
      {{- loop.last ? ' and ' : (not loop.first ? ', ') -}}
      {{- author -}}
     {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
```

The output is something like

- For 1 author

  Author1
- For 2 authors

  Author1 and Author2
- For 3 or more authors

  Author1, Author2, and Author3